# What is the name of this discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have done a bit of googling, and can't find the 'name' of the random variable $N$ taking values in $\{1,2,3,...\} $ with

$$ P(N= n) = \frac{c}{n^2}$$

(where the value of $c$ is forced to be $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$).

Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't exist, I would go with "discrete Cauchy", but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random variable with pmf:

$$ P(N= n) = \frac{6}{\pi^2 n^2}  \quad \quad \text{for } n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$$

is said to have a **Lotka** distribution.

*Reference:*

> Lotka, A.J. (1926), The frequency distribution of scientific productivity, *Journal of the Washington Academy of Sciences* 16, 317-323.

The Riemann Zeta distribution referred to in other answers is a more general distribution that happens to nest the Lotka as a special case. But then so do many other distributions, including the Dubey, TriGamma, Zipf and Zipf-Mandelbrot. This distribution is no more a Zeta than any of the others. Moreover, it would appear that Lotka's paper predates any published papers on the Riemann Zeta distribution.

Comment: Nice. I will withdraw my zeta answer.

Answer (score 1):

Zeta distribution, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution where parameter = 2.